# subtract a dataframe by another dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two dataframe with identical index in both dataframes. I want to perform subtract operation. i.e., I want to subtract the all columns in `df1` with respect to `df2` column. where df2 has only one column.

Input:

df1

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    10    34     6
1     3    23   123
2    23    45    23
3     5     1     5
4     1    45     6
5    65     6    88
```

df2

```
   base
0    12
1    43
2   435
3    76
4    23
5    12
```

I tried,

```
df1-df2['base']
```

Results,

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5  col1  col2  col3
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

But Expected.

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    -2    22    -6
1   -40   -20    80
2  -412  -390  -412
3   -71   -75   -71
4   -22    22   -17
5    53    -6    76
```

1. Why I'am getting NaN and how two df's combined?
2. How to get expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.substract` with argument `axis=0`

```
df1.subtract(df2['base'], axis=0)
```

[out]

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    -2    22    -6
1   -40   -20    80
2  -412  -390  -412
3   -71   -75   -71
4   -22    22   -17
5    53    -6    76
```